# ImmutableID of the user missing when trying to acquire a token for MS Graph API (Windows auth)

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, windows-authentication, azure-ad-msal, ntlm

I'm developing an API that uses the Microsoft Graph Client SDK to make multiples calls to a Sharepoint site.

To authenticate the users making the calls to the API, I'm using the Integrated Windows Provider method, with this very simple code:

```
var clientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(_apiSettings.Value.AzureClientId)
    .WithTenantId(_apiSettings.Value.AzureTenantId)
    .Build();

var token = clientApp.AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth(new string[] { _apiSettings.Value.MicrosoftGraphApiScopeUrl })
    .ExecuteAsync().Result;
```

When calling the method containing this code in local, it works flawlessly. But when I deploy the app to our test server, and by using the NTLM authentication with the same user than in local, I'm having this error:

> Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException: AADSTS90020: The
> SAML 1.1 Assertion is missing ImmutableID of the user.

When printing the content of the HttpContext.User, I see that the same user, connected to the same group, is both used on the "online" and the local version.

I already tried adding this header, but it's not doing anything:

```
var immId = new Dictionary<string, string>();
immId.Add("Prefer", "IdType=\"ImmutableId\"");

var token = clientApp.AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth(new string[] { _apiSettings.Value.MicrosoftGraphApiScopeUrl })
    .WithExtraHttpHeaders(immId)
    .ExecuteAsync().Result;
```

What can I do ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your application don't have the  **admin to consent** to the application.You will get the `MsalUiRequiredException`.

Try with the adding the **[admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#requesting-consent-for-an-entire-tenant)** to application .

Or Try with  adding tenant admin **selected the Grant/revoke admin consent for {tenant domain}** button on the API permissions tab of the registration for the application. For more information, see [Add permissions to access your web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#add-permissions-to-access-your-web-api).

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token-integrated-windows-authentication?tabs=java)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already did grand the admin consent for the tenant domain. I'm not sure that there is just one kind of "MsalUiRequiredException", so the message is important too: "AADSTS90020: The SAML 1.1 Assertion is missing ImmutableID of the user". I'm note sure that this error is related to the solution you provided.